# Sharing an assembly between ASP.NET and Silverlight

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight, assemblies, versioning

I've created an assembly to share it between my main app and the silverlight app. At the beginning it looked like it was going to work but now I get this exception: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException was caught, Message="Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml.Linq".  I'm using .NET 3.5 Sp1 and Silverlight 3.

That shared assembly uses System.Xml.Linq, and it cannot find it... I think because it is trying to find that version in the .NET framework instead looking in the silverlight one. How can I fix this?

Cheers.

PS: this is the full exception output:

---

System.IO.FileNotFoundException was caught
  Message="Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
  Source="MyApp.Metadata"
  FileName="System.Xml.Linq, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
  FusionLog="=== Pre-bind state information ===\r\nLOG: User = IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool\r\nLOG: DisplayName = System.Xml.Linq, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\n (Fully-specified)\r\nLOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/vtortola.MyApp/Documents/MyApp/MyAppSAS/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/\r\nLOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\vtortola.MyApp\Documents\MyApp\MyAppSAS\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\bin\r\nCalling assembly : MyApp.Metadata, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.\r\n===\r\nLOG: This bind starts in default load context.\r\nLOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\vtortola.MyApp\Documents\MyApp\MyAppSAS\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\web.config\r\nLOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Aspnet.config\r\nLOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.\r\nLOG: Post-policy reference: System.Xml.Linq, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\r\nLOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.\r\n"
  StackTrace:
       at MyApp.Metadata.MyAppEntity.Deserialize(String message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must maintain two separate projects - one for desktop and for Silverlight. Have a look here for more information:

[How can I use non-Silverlight assemblies in a Silverlight app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721375)

You can share most of the code between projects (as in link files from one to another). Here is the Microsoft page that describes how to do exactly this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648215.aspx