# How to use non-Silverlight DLL's in Silverlight applications?

Tags: silverlight

How to use non-Silverlight DLL's in Silverlight applications? I cannot reference them in my Silverlight application, but I can in the Web projects which runs the Silverlight app. Is there a way for my Silverlight app to somehow use the DLL in the Web project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use non-Silverlight assemblies in a Silverlight app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721375/how-can-i-use-non-silverlight-assemblies-in-a-silverlight-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight uses a subset of the CLR called the CoreCLR. You will need to recompile your CLR assemblies against the CoreCLR to use them in Silverlight.

Comment: @Val - and how you did that ? In Visual Studio ?

Comment: @Jasper Yes, in VS 2010, create a new Silverlight Component project, add all .CS files of the non-Silverlight DLL and compile.

Comment: @Val - After reading you comment people start thinking that just **any** project could be recompiled for SL (for example: Log4Net, NUnit, etc..). But I understand what you trying to say